# Oracle setting up on k8s cluster using helm charts enterprise edition

Tags: oracle, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, enterprise

[FATAL] [DBT-05509] Failed to connect to the specified database (ORCLCDB).
CAUSE: OS Authentication might be disabled for this database (ORCLCDB).
ACTION: Specify a valid sysdba user name and password to connect to the database.
cat: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ORCLCDB/ORCLCDB.log: No such file or directory
cat: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ORCLCDB.log: No such file or directory
im facing this error when setting up oracle on k8s cluster using helm charts

im not sure what to do exactly i tried accessing the opt dir didnt find the oracle dir , as well as i cannot enter the pod as its not running

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.